# Go Lang custom convert array into string with two separators

Tags: strings, array, go

This is my custom function to join strings from an array into one string.
We can provide normal separator and the last one. `JoinStringsIntoArray(", ", " and ", words...)`

```
func JoinStringsIntoArray(sep string, lastSep string, words ...string) string {
lastElementIndex := len(words) - 1
var joinedString string

for index, word := range words[0:lastElementIndex] {
    if index == lastElementIndex-1 {
        sep = lastSep
    }
    joinedString += word + sep
}

joinedString += words[lastElementIndex]

    return joinedString
}
```

Test for this function

```
func TestStringsJoinsWithCommas(t *testing.T) {
    var words []string
    words = append(words, "one", "two", "three")

    expectedResult := "one, two and three"
    result := JoinStringsIntoArray(", ", " and ", words...)

    if expectedResult != result {
        t.Errorf("Strings joiner is broken, it should be '%v', we got '%v'", expectedResult, result)
    }
}
```

What do you think about this, can this solution be improved? The function works fine but I'm not so sure it's written well.

Answer (score 1):

The Go standard library `strings` package has a `Join` function:

```
func Join(elems []string, sep string) string
```

Your function is a simple extension of `strings.Join`:

```
func JoinLast(elems []string, sep, lastSep string) string
```

However, for no obvious reason, you chose a different function parameter signature:

```
func JoinLast(sep string, lastSep string, words ...string) string
```

We need a comment to explain why this isn't an arbitrary or idiosyncratic decision.

---

Your testing is inadequate. Check boundary conditions. Your function fails on an empty `words` list.

```
words = []string{}
```

---

You have not provided any `testing` benchmarks. For example,

```
BenchmarkJoin-4   5534918  207.9 ns/op   104 B/op  5 allocs/op
```

```
func JoinStringsIntoArray(sep string, lastSep string, words ...string) string {
    lastElementIndex := len(words) - 1
    var joinedString string

    for index, word := range words[0:lastElementIndex] {
        if index == lastElementIndex-1 {
            sep = lastSep
        }
        joinedString += word + sep
    }

    joinedString += words[lastElementIndex]

    return joinedString
}

func BenchmarkJoin(b *testing.B) {
    words := []string{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        JoinStringsIntoArray(", ", " and ", words...)
    }
}
```

---

You can do better. For example, minimize allocation,

```
BenchmarkJoin-4  16612879   70.95 ns/op   32 B/op  1 allocs/op
```

```
func JoinLast(elems []string, sep, lastSep string) string {
    var join strings.Builder
    joinCap := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(elems); i++ {
        joinCap += len(elems[i])
    }
    if len(elems) > 1 {
        joinCap += len(lastSep)
        if len(elems) > 2 {
            joinCap += (len(elems) - 2) * len(sep)
        }
    }
    join.Grow(joinCap)

    last := len(elems) - 1 - 1
    for i, elem := range elems {
        if i >= last {
            if i == last {
                sep = lastSep
            } else {
                sep = ""
            }
        }
        join.WriteString(elem)
        join.WriteString(sep)
    }

    return join.String()
}

func BenchmarkJoin(b *testing.B) {
    words := []string{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        JoinLast(words, ", ", " and ")
    }
}
```